# EC2: map multiple applications to different domains

Tags: amazon-ec2

i'm playing with EC2 and i've been able to create my instance that has a django appliacation on port 80, and a tomcat on 8080.
now, with elastic IP i can manage to redirect my domain to django application.
now i would like to map subdomains to each tomact applications.
for example

```
django app (ec2...:80) --> mydomain.com
tomcat (ec2...:8080) --> tomcat.mydomain.com
webbapp1 (ec2...:8080/webapp1/) --> webapp1.mydomain.com
```

is this possible with the free account?

ciao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reverse proxy. I'd recommend using Nginx for this.

Before doing this, you'll need to move your Django app to a different port, as the reverse proxy is going to need to bind to port 80. For example, move it to port 8081.

Here's an example config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # Forward to Django
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    server_name tomcat.mydomain.com

    # Forward to Tomcat
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try it out later on once i've time :).
one thing. in the domain provider, i set only the www and @ domains to the machine ip? that's it?